# ros launch issue

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I have just started learning Ros with the help of Ros tutorials the problem which i am facing is that according to Ros tutorials  link http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRxconsoleRoslaunch
when i type roslaunch command in the new terminal it gives me an error that
danishraza@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace$ roscd beginner_tutorials
roscd: No such package 'beginner_tutorials'

I have Ubuntu 10.04 Lts on my machine and Ros electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28085/ros-launch-issue/) by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial assumes you have created the 'beginner_tutorials' package in the preceding tutorial on [Creating a ROS Package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on 2012-02-22**:
i have already created the package but the problem is still there kindly suggest some another answer.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-02-22**:
Then you most likely don't have your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH set up correctly, so your 'beginner_tutorials' package is not found by ROS. Have a look at this guide: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment